# How to use "lock into place"

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

Can you use "lock into place" like this?

I thought "lock into place" was an idiom, but I couldn't find it. It seems to be a phrase that's not an idiom, so I was wondering if the following sentence made sense.

> Her eyelids lock into place and because of that she could no longer
> close her eyes.

Comment: It's an odd way to say that her eyelids were stuck open, or simply, that she couldn't close her eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lock into" is a *phrasal verb*. It means to *secure something into position*.

You'll find 'lock into' in plenty of dictionaries, just not 'lock into place' because that's too specific - you could lock something 'into place', or 'into position' etc